# Is it possible to write a using declaration for a method of a member, similar to a inherented method?

Tags: c++, c++17

It is possible to write a `using` declaration to e.g. promote a private base class method to being public in a derived class, i.e. `B::foo` in the example. Is it possible to do something similar to make a method available *without the need to write another method*?

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    int m_number{ 99 };
protected:
    int foo() { return m_number; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::foo;
};

class C
{
    B m_a;
public:
    using foo() = m_a.foo(); // is something like this possible?
};


int main() { 
    B b;
    std::cout<<b.foo();

    C c;
    std::cout<<c.foo();
}
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. Now, why don't you ask about your problem, instead of what *you think* is the solution.

Comment: @StoryTeller There is no specific problem I need to solve that involves the above topic. It would just be a way to make things more compact. That's all.

Comment: Then ask about *that*. Who knows what solution there may exists that you don't perceive yet. It would be more productive than this dead end question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to do this. In order to understand why, you need to understand that the purpose of a `using` declaration is to affect the name lookup algorithm, by making a name appear somewhere else from where it was originally declared.

The declaration in `B` that reads:

```
using A::foo;
```

has the effect of causing the lookup for the name `foo` in the scope of `B` to find the member `A::foo`. It does not create a new `foo` method that takes `B*` as the `this` pointer and forwards the call to `A::foo`; it simply causes the function `A::foo` to appear elsewhere (that is, in `B`).

A `using` declaration cannot result in the generation of any new code, such as that which would be necessary to forward a call by invoking a method on a member. If you want a new method, you'll just have to write it yourself.